# Disparar evento ou pressionar o botão do mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou aplicando um evento `change` no id `#estado`, isso tem que acontecer quando efetuo um clique no id `#cidade`.

Esto funcionando, porém notei que so ocorre quando clico e solto o botão, como faço para ele ocorrer quando eu clicar?

**OBS:** se eu clicar e ficar segurando o evento não ocorre, ele so vai ocorrer quando eu soltar o botão do mouse.

```
$("#cidade").on("click", function () {
    $("#estado").change();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso podes usar o `"mousedown"` em vêz de `"click"`. Assim quando o mouse é premido ele corre a callback.

Caso queiras suporte para tablets junta também o `touchstart`. O código poderia ser assim:

```
$("#cidade").on("mousedown touchstart", function () {
    $("#estado").change();
});
```